# Ternary Statement With DrawTextValuePair

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, drawtext

I am getting an error thrown when the text box value is null, so I was trying to write a ternary statement to check if the value is null.  This is what I cam up with:

```
DrawTextValuePair(e, string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_pcl.pn.Text) ? String.Format("Input: ", m_pcl.pn.Text) : String.Format("Input: "), true, m_leftMargin);
```

But in using such I get a compile error of:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'iLeftMargin' of 'ProfileDocument.DrawTextValuePair(PrintPageEventArgs, string, string, bool, int)'

What would be the proper way to utilize a ternary statement in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method

```
ProfileDocument.DrawTextValuePair(PrintPageEventArgs, string, string, bool, int)
```

expects 5 arguments, but you provided it with only 4:

```
DrawTextValuePair(
    e, // 1st
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_pcl.pn.Text) ? String.Format("Input: ", m_pcl.pn.Text) : String.Format("Input: "), // 2nd
    true, // 3rd
    m_leftMargin // 4th
);
```

Comment: hah, so nothing is wrong with my ternary statement, just providing the wrong number of arguments!

Comment: @YohanGreenburg Exactly! That's why the error message tells that. :p

Comment: @Dmitry No offence but code can be simplified. Second string format is redundant. Shouldn't we keep to good practices and when we using string alias once than keep to it everywhere? I know the string thing is just meather of coding standard but still...?

Comment: @KrzysztofLa I agree, but how it relates to the topic?

Comment: @Dmitry It is not. It was btw your good answer. I always thought it matters to keep with good practices when reviewing someone's code. But whatever. End of topic.

Comment: @KrzysztofLa I agree, code review is very important part of the development. This is why code review is always welcome here: [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You could participate. :p